# Tensorflow: How to index one tensor using another tensor with unknown dimensions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `params` with shape `(?, 70, 64)` and another tensor `indices` with shape `(?, 1)`. I want to index into the first tensor's axis 1 using the second tensor, to get a result with shape `(?, 64)`.

I can't figure how to go about it. Here's what I've tried:

```
tf.gather(params, indices)           # returns a tensor of shape (?, 1, 70, 64)
tf.gather(params, indices, axis=1)   # returns a tensor of shape (?, ?, 1, 64)
tf.gather_nd(params, indices)        # returns a tensor of shape (?, 70, 64)
```

(I have an older version of TensorFlow, which doesn't have `batch_gather`. )
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.stack` to convert your indices to a tensor of shape `(?, 2)` with the first number in the second dimension being the batch number. Then using this new indices with `tf.gather_nd` should give you what you want if I understand your goal correctly.

Since your `indices` is a tensor of shape `(?, 1)`, `batch_gather` would give you `(?, 1, 64)`, meaning one reshape step from your expected result tensor of shape `(?, 64)`. The following code shows two methods give you the same result:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

params = tf.constant(np.arange(3*70*64).reshape(3, 70, 64))
init_indices = tf.constant([[2], [1], [0]])
indices = tf.stack(
    [tf.range(init_indices.shape[0]), tf.reshape(init_indices, [-1])],
    axis=1
)
output = tf.gather_nd(params, indices)
batch_gather = tf.reshape(tf.batch_gather(params, init_indices),
                          [params.shape[0], -1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('tf.gather_nd')
    print(output.shape)
    print(sess.run(output))
    print('batch_gather')
    print(batch_gather.shape)
    print(sess.run(batch_gather))
```

## Edit on comment "first dimension unknown"

Overall, the optimal solution depends on the specific use case, and to use `tf.gather_nd` with `tf.stack`, the key is to get the batch size, i.e. the first dimension. One way, which again may not be optimal, is to use `tf.shape`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

params = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 70, 64), dtype=tf.int32)
init_indices = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int32)
indices = tf.stack(
    [tf.range(tf.shape(init_indices)[0]), tf.reshape(init_indices, [-1])],
    axis=1
)
output = tf.gather_nd(params, indices)
batch_gather = tf.reshape(tf.batch_gather(params, init_indices),
                          [tf.shape(params)[0], -1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('tf.gather_nd')
    print(output.shape)
    print(sess.run(
        output, feed_dict={params: np.arange(3*70*64).reshape(3, 70, 64),
                           init_indices: [[2], [1], [0]]}
    ))
    print('batch_gather')
    print(batch_gather.shape)
    print(sess.run(
        batch_gather, feed_dict={params: np.arange(3*70*64).reshape(3, 70, 64),
                                 init_indices: [[2], [1], [0]]}
    ))
```

One thing to point out is because batch size is unknown, `print(batch_gather.shape)` gives `(?, ?)` rather than `(?, 64)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll have to spend some time making sure I understand how tf.stack works here, but one issue that I see in the above solution is that tf.stack is using tf.range(init_indices.shape[0]), which is defined in your example, but is unknown in my use case.

Comment: @user2966082 Thank you for point this out. Updated with one solution.